# How to obtain PR form git via GitPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github

I need a means to make accessible a PR from a fork submitted to a repository via GitPython. Once I have the PR and it's commits available I should be able to use it how I plan to, but so far haven't seen any support to pull/clone commits included in a Peer Review from a fork. Does anyone know if this isn't supported or am I overlooking it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It took longer than I'd like to admit, but I believe I figured out what was needed.

`repo = git.Repo('name_of_repo')
repo.remotes.fetch(refspec='pull/#/head')`

Comment: Strange code. You don't have any var named `repos` and even if you'd have it you shouldn't loop over a list of repos to fetch PRs; you need to loop over a list of branches or PR numbers.